# MAAS No MBR magic after deploy Ubuntu

Tags: maas, mbr

I have tried to deploy the Openstack-base bundle from juju, and I've tried straight deploy Ubuntu 18.04 from MAAS. After the bare metal hardware goes through the full intall of Ubuntu, when it reboots, it fails with a message saying No MBR magic. Something else about treating the disk as raw, then Booting ... and just stays there and never boots up. Is the Ubuntu image in MAAS failing to install the boot loaded?

Answer (score 1):

My storage controller configuration on the hosts were the issue. During initial commissioning MAAS took the wrong disk as the boot disk. Changing the boot device in the storage configuration of each host resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I enable "UEFI" for Network boot at BIOS. And retry commissioning, deploying than it works well.

Comment: Answer needs more detail. What is this "And retry consuming, deploying than it works well." ?